# Auto generate columns in Microsoft Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can we auto generate column/fields in microsoft access table ?

Scenario......
I have a table with personal details of my employee (EmployDetails)
I wants to put their everyday attendance in an another table.
Rather using separate records for everyday, I want to use a single record for an employ..
Eg :    I wants to create a table with fields like below 
        EmployID, 01Jan2020, 02Jan2020, 03Jan2020,.........25May2020 and so on.......
It means everyday I have to generate a column automatically...
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify how you are accessing the Access table. Are you using the Access UI or some other software?

Comment: The best way is to just have a table with a row for employee / date. Why do you want to add new columns?

Comment: It's a good practice to include some code in your question. You tagged this as [tag:javascript], [tag:java] and [tag:vbscript]. So I expect you to show us some definitions for your tables, examples of data and so on. Use markdown to format your data examples. They are tables, so they should look like tables. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26227017).

Comment: _everyday I have to generate a column automatically_ ... no you don't, Access is not a spreadsheet, and you would run out of fields as a table can only hold 255 fields. Use the answer by Sox and create a _crosstab_ query which will provide the output you request.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would define columns manually (whether that is through a UI or SQL).

With the information given I think the proper solution is to have two tables.

You have your "EmployDetails" which you would put their general info (name, contact information etc), and the key which would be the employee ID (unique, can be autogenerated or manual, just needs to be unique)

You would have a second table with a foreign key to the empployee ID in "EmployDetails" with a column called Date, and another called details (or whatever you are trying to capture in your date column idea).

Then you simply add rows for each day. Then you do a join query between the tables to look up all the "days" for an employee. This is called normalisation and how relational databases (such as Access) are designed to be used.

Employee Table:

```
EmpID |  NAME  | CONTACT
----------------------
 1    |  Jim   | 222-2222
 2    |  Jan   | 555-5555
```

Detail table:

```
DetailID | EmpID (foreign key) | Date     | Hours_worked | Notes
-------------------------------------------------------------
10231    | 1                   | 01Jan2020| 5            | Lazy Jim took off early
10233    | 2                   | 02Jan2020| 8            | Jan is a hard worker
10240    | 1                   | 02Jan2020| 7.5          | Finally he stays a full day
```

To find what Jim worked you do a join:

```
SELECT Employee.EmpID, Employee.Name, Details.Date, Details.Hours_worked, Details.Notes
FROM Employee
JOIN Details ON Employee.EmpID=Details.EmpID;
```

Of course this will give you a normalised result (which is generally what's wanted so you can iterate over it):

```
EmpID |  NAME  | Date      | Hours_worked | Notes
-----------------------------------------------
1     | Jim    | 01Jan2020 | 5            | ......
1     | Jim    | 02Jan2020 | 7            | .......
```

If you want the results denormalised you'll have to look into pivot tables.

See [more on creating foreign keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your concern.  But actually I need it to be get like the following spread sheet
EmployID      Total Of STATUS 01 JAN 2020 02 JAN 2020 03 JAN 2020 .....
JC768421A     2                          P                   P         A
JC768422W     3                           P                   P                P

I was trying to get this result by using a cross table query in Ms Access.
But now I am facing a problem... If I use cross table then how can I create a grid view by using this Cross Table ?

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? You need to clarify. You have javascript, java and vbscript as tags. Is this a winforms app? A web app or web page? Once you have the data, you can display it however you want if you are writing code. If you are using the Access user interface things are a bit more limited. You should clarify that in your question.